# Is it possible to apply for a UK spouse-visa (for wife) while the actual UK citizen lives outside the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, uk-citizens, family, spouses

Not sure if this is the right site to ask this, but is it possible to apply for a UK Spouse visa (for wife) while the actual UK citizen lives outside the UK?

I plan to move to the UK, but am thinking of sorting out the spouse visa before i leave.

Can't seem to find clear info on this scenario on gov.co.uk

Comment: Just to clarify - you want to apply for a visa for your spouse to visit the UK, but you are not in the UK yourself?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I think they're talking about [this type of visa](https://www.gov.uk/join-family-in-uk/eligibility), although OP is indeed a bit unclear.

Comment: Yes @Burhan..Correct. i plan to move to the UK but thinking of sorting out the spouse Visa before i leave.

Comment: Can we migrate this to Expats?

Comment: Although a good question, but as its for moving permanently, better suited for expats.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**, this is a very common type of situation where a Brit has been living abroad with their spouse and now wants to repatriate.  It's called a "spouse visa", and the controlling technical reference is [Paragraph 281 of the Immigration Rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-8-family-members).

The hurdles for qualifying are listed in [Appendix FM](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-fm-family-members), which was enacted by Parliament in 2010 and also forms part of the rules.

Terminology wise, you are the 'sponsor' and your spouse is the 'applicant'. To start, the spouse creates an account at [Visa4UK](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/home/welcome) and fills out the form.

Gathering the right evidence is key-critical, it's best to take future questions up at [Expats](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/).  Your question is possibly off-topic here because I cannot tell if you are visiting your spouse or what your status is abroad.